# Finding unknown from differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have an equation that looks like $$X' = a \sin(X) + b \cos(X) + c$$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are constants. For given values of $a, b$ and $c$ how can I calculate X? I have set of values for $a, b$ and $c$ and I am looking for an equation that could solve for $X$ or other approaches like numerical methods are also ok. Thanks in advance.

My approach is as below:
$$X' = a \sin(X) + b \cos(X) + c \ (Integrating \ this \ eqn)$$
$$X = d \cos(X) + b \sin(X) + cX \\where(d = -a)$$
$$X = p\sin(X + q) + cX \\where \ p= sqrt(d^2 + b^2) \ and \ cosq = d/p ,\ sinq=b/p$$
$$X(1-c)/p = sin(X+q) \\ where \ p/(1-c) = r$$
$$X - rsin(X+q) = 0$$
$$f(X) = X - r \ sin(X+q) \\ f'(X) = 1 - rcos(X+q)$$
To the above equations I applied Newton's method:
$$X(n+1) = X(n) - f(X(n))/f'(X(n)) \\ X(0) = 1$$
I run this for 2000 Iterations and found theat the solution is not converging to expected result. Is there something wrong with the mathematical derication ? or It is not possible to get results from this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my gut feeling says that an analytical solution would be very complicated ... It's easier to just try a numerical solution. Newton/Runge-Kutta with a small time step, perhaps ?

Comment: Your approach is wrong. On the left you integrate by $t$, on the right you integrate by $X$, but you need to integrate the same on both sides. Apply separation of variables first.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Could you please help me by elaborating what you said.

Answer (score 2):

#### direct transformation using half-angle formulas

The probably best systematic method (from integrals of quotients of trigonometric expressions) is the half-angle tangent substitution. Set $U=\tan(X/2)$, then $\sin(X)=\frac{2U}{1+U^2}$, $\cos(X)=\frac{1-U^2}{1+U^2}$ and
$$
U'=(1+U^2)X'=2aU+b(1-U^2)+c(1+U^2)
$$
which now has a quadratic right side and can be solved via partial fraction decomposition. Or one can see it as a Riccati equation, and get with the further substitution $U=\frac{V'}{(b-c)V}$ a second order linear ODE with constant coefficients.

---

#### correct integration using separation of variables

As to your edit: separation of variables leads to
$$
\int\frac{dX}{a\sin X+b\cos X+c}=t+k.
$$
Here then you proceed with the integral of a rational trigonometric expression, naturally inviting to apply the half angle formula.

---

#### direct approach continued, (implicit) partial fraction decomposition

You can solve the transformed equation or the integral by finding the roots of the quadratic, so that
$$
U' = (c-b)(U-r_1)(U-r_2)
$$
and the appropriate transformation is $V=\frac{U-r_1}{U-r_2}$ transforming it into a linear first order ODE.
$$
V'=\frac{r_1-r_2}{(U-r_2)^2}U'=(r_1-r_2)(c-b)V\implies V=Ce^{(r_1-r_2)(c-b)t}
$$
where the roots $r_k$ are of the quadratic equation $[(c-b)r]^2-2a[(c-b)r]+(c^2-b^2)=0$.

---

#### using the approach via a second order linear ODE

A more direct solution comes from the Riccati transformation into a second order ODE, $V=\exp((b-c)\int U\,dt)$, so that
$$
\frac{V''}{(b-c)V}-\frac{V'^2}{(b-c)V^2}=(b+c)+2a\frac{V'}{(b-c)V}-(b-c)\frac{V'^2}{(b-c)^2V^2}
\\\implies
V''-2aV'+(c^2-b^2)V=0
$$
which again is easy to solve, and the back-substitutions here are IMO easiest to perform.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the equation as
$$\frac 1 {t'}=a \sin(x)+b \cos(x)+c$$ you should get
$$t+k=-\frac{2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{a+(c-b) \tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}$$ where $k$ would be fixed by initial conditions.

Solving for $x$ would then give
$$x=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2} \tanh \left(\frac{1}{2} (k+t)
   \sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}\right)+a}{b-c}\right)$$

Comment: Of course the distinction between trigonometric and hyperbolic functions depends on the sign of $a^2+b^2-c^2$.

Comment: @LutzL. For sure but if we accept to work with complex numbers, thsi would not make problems. Your solution is very nice (as usual). $\to +1$. Cheers :-)